# Adding server-side rendered elements as children to Vue js parent

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I have a server side rendered page with "orders" and a root Vue object instantiated as a "parent object". Is it possible to initiate the rendered html orders as children to that parent Vue object?

Vue js seems to work best when dynamically adding content, but in this case I want to be able to add children to a parent from pre-existing markup. Is it even possible? I tried to find solutions but I cant get it to work. Basically, I have several divs on the site like this

`<div id="order-1">some content</div><div id="order-2">some other content</div>`

I want to add them as children to a Vue component that I have initiated with `"new Vue({..."` with its element set on body.

So basically I want this structure

> Parent App (using new Vue)
>   --> Order 1 (added as child after page render)
>   --> Order 2 (added as child after page render)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding ajax content to your component.

for this you need to recompile that component or instance to act that ajax content is already part of vue instance.

after completing ajax request you can fire :

```
Vue.$compile(this.$el);
```

where

> this.$el

will be your current element or your component

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use global components, you need to inject them in your renderer before you return your root app component so they are available server side. Vue server-side can't render a component it doesn't have access to or a definition for.